# How do I permanently map Shift-Right to PageUp on xubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, xubuntu, xmodmap, setxkbmap

I got myself a laptop and the keyboard is slightly goofed up because the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is in a place where I have typically had the <kbd>PageUp</kbd> key. So, I wanted to figure out how to remap the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to <kbd>PageUp</kbd>.

I ran

```
xmodmap -pke > /tmp/xmodmap.conf
```

and found out that the keycode for the right Shift is 62. So, I edited the `/tmp/xmodmap.conf` file so that keycode 62 maps to "Prior" (which I found out was PageUp) and then I ran

```
xmodmap /tmp/xmodmap.conf
```

The "Shift" key on the right side of my keyboard was then able to do a "Page Up." Neat! Then, I copied that `/tmp/xmodmap.conf` file into my home directory (`/home/someUser/`) and put the command

```
xmodmap /home/someUser/xmodmap.conf
```

into `/etc/rc.local`. But the right Shift key did NOT map to PageUp on the next boot!

Note that I have already added `XKbOptions` into my `/etc/default/keyboard` to `ctrl:nocaps` and that works beautifully. What I am wondering is if someone can help me set this new mapping (Right Shift to PageUp) in `/etc/default/keyboard` so that the mapping will work on the virtual consoles as well as in X/XFCE.

This is being run on a 64-bit Xubuntu 12.10 installation.

Comment: thanks "@slhck" for the edits. The questions looks much nicer/neater and readable now.